# How to create multi-page node views in D7

Tags: nodes

I have a content type with user related fields that users can fill out, similar to a profile. I would like to split this node into a series of sub-pages/multipages and group fields together on each sub-page, rather than having all fields show as one huge node.

It's very similar to having tabs or a pager system but I don't want the actual tabs or pagers to be visible since I need to have my own links to each "tab"/multipage. I have tried to do this with Field Group module but it doesn't allow multipage groups in the node view (only in the node edit form). If I create Field Group tabs, that does split the node but then I have no way to hide the actual tab labels and (as far as I know) it is awkward trying to link to each of the individual tabs since they don't have a proper url. If it were possible to create additional local task tabs (after View, Edit) each tab would have its own url (node/#/edit, node/#/info, etc), and I could then hide, sort and rename the tabs very easily using Tab Tamer. But it's my understanding that there's no module with this sort of "add a local tab" functionality.

Is there currently a way to create multipages with D7, in the node view?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the Book module which comes with core? It will do some bits of what you need but you can build a module to further modify it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. The problem with the Book module is that it doesn't allow you to set a default number of child pages and the kind of fields in each of those pages, it only allows you to set the default fields for the first book page. As a profile this is not practical since when a new user signs up they would need to have a profile with all the default fields and pages created for them, and not have to add the pages and fields manually themselves. At the moment I am considering using Views or Panels to create the 'menu tabs', but I'm not sure if the tab labels can be hidden.